# Typescript type deduction, return type of callback within interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

Hello In this snippet below,

```js
interface FormHandlerProps<Values, Errors> extends FormikProps<Values>  {
    globalErrors: Errors
}
type FormHandlerConfig<Values, Errors> = {
    globalValidate?: (values: Values) => Errors
    children?: ((props: FormHandlerProps<Values, Errors>) => React.ReactNode) | React.ReactNode 
}
```

the Errors generic type is inferred as unknown if I define both *globalValidate* and *children(...)*. However if I only define *globalValidate* the type deduction works properly. How can I make the Errors generic parameter from `(props: FormHandlerProps<Values, Errors` be properly deduced from the return type of *globalValidate*

Example:

```js
                <FormHandler
                    initialValues={initValues}
                    onSubmit={(data) => handleSubmit(data, preferences, onSubmit)}
                    globalValidate={() => {
                        return "test" ;
                    }}
                    validate={(data) =>
                        validate(data, preferences, initValues, onError, {
                            isWrongModeLabel: t("preferences:text.wrong-operator"),
                            onErrorLabel: t("preferences:confirmation.error-messages.carpool"),
                        })
                    }
                >
                    {({ errors, globalErrors }) => (

                    )}
               </FormHandler>
```

In this example above the return type of *globalValidate* is correct (string). But if I add data as paramter

```js
                    globalValidate={(data) => {
                        return "test" ;
                    }}
```

Then the return type is unknown, and the attribute *globalErrors* in the children callback is unknown as well.

**Nb: If children is not a function, the return type is correct**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you please add an example usage of those types?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: One more thing... how is `FormHandler` declared?